# Joda Time - repeating/weekly Interval

Tags: java, jodatime, java-time

I want to convert a string like the following to an object that can evaluate an instant to be withing a periodic interval or not:

```
Mon: 0800-1300
```

I am looking for some kind of functionality that I could use similar to this pseudocode:

```
class IntervalHolder {

    private PeriodicInterval interval;

    public IntervalHolder(String intervalString) {
        interval = Interval.parse(intervalString)
    }

    public boolean isWithinInterval(Instant instant) {
        return interval.contains(instant);
    }
```

Interval from Yoda time seems "to work only once" in that case, because an instant also always specifies the date. Is there a class in the framework that would work for checking weekly intervals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option in Joda Time because all the relevant classes would either contain full information about time boundaries (that is the case with `Duration` and `Interval`) or would store a period in given unit (that is the case with `Period`).

I would recommend simply (of course with exporting all the constants to separate variables):

```
public boolean isWithinInterval(Instant instant) {
    DateTime dateTime = instant.toDateTime();
    return dateTime.getDayOfWeek() == MONDAY
           && dateTime.getHourOfDay() >= 8
           && dateTime.getHourOfDay() <= 13;
```

Note that you could of course create separate `Duration` and `Period` objects and use both of them in the comparison but I don't think this would be cleaner than the presented solution.